# Removing all stopwords from a list of words

Tags: python, performance, natural-language-processing

What is the fastest Pythonic way to remove all stopwords from a list of words in a document? Right now I am using a list comprehension that contains a `for` loop.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

''' Push stopwords to a list '''
stop = stopwords.words('english')
Document = ' Some huge text .......................... '
''' Tokenize the doc '''
words = nltk.word_tokenize(Document)
''' Comparing two lists '''
stopwordsfree_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop]
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `stop` is a list containing \$s\$ stopwords, and `words` is a list containing \$w\$ words, then the loop in the list comprehension will be \$O(w s)\$, since it basically has to iterate over both lists in a nested loop.

However, if you make the stopwords into a `set`…

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

… then each lookup can be done in \$O(1)\$ time.  You would get \$O(w)\$ running time just by changing the data structure like that.

Another minor issue is that [by convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), `Document` should be lowercase, because it is a variable rather than a class.

Comment: Oh, so sets in python are like dictionaries with no values. Thanks that helps.